# Is there any downtime or regression on scaling PU in event hub

Tags: azure-eventhub

I have premium azure event hub. I want to scale the PU of the event hub namespace from 1 to 2.
I want to know whether there is any downtime or any regression in this process. I could not find anything in the documentation.
Since our product is real time we do not want any down time for our customers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there should be no downtime observed when PU setting is changed.